# Nhibernate mapping tool for MySQL

Tags: mysql, nhibernate-mapping

Is there any mapping tool for nhibernate-mysql? I want a mapping tool that

1. Takes in a MySQL database
2. General the relevant hbm.xml file
3. Create the data access layer class that maps to each table.

Is there any such tools available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) has such a tool available.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one tool similar to what you describe which is called ActiveWriter which is a VStudio addon. It is useful but have some serious limitations.
I would consider using NHibernate Fluent or ActiveRecords instead.

Answer (score 2):

This popped up on the NHibernate users group some time back. General feeling was that it's a bag of hurt generating hbm.xml from database. Better to write classes and XML files.

One guy [suggested](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/16b2019f456f21e6/fa1fd001bc7db02c?lnk=gst&q=generate+hbm.xml+from+database#fa1fd001bc7db02c) MyGeneration, which might be worth a look.